# value never used/ missing return statement

Tags: java, return

I'm doing an exercise where i have to write a method that returns the index of the largest element in an array.

The code is this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IndexLargestElement {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter 10 double values");

     double[] list = new double [10];
     for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
       list[i] = input.nextDouble();

     int index = indexOfLargestElement(list);

     System.out.println("The index of the largest element is " + index);
  }    

  public static int indexOfLargestElement(double[] array){
    double max = array[0];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] > max) {
        max = array[i];
        index = i;
        return index;
      }
    }
}
```

Now at int index=0; and max = array[i];  Netbeans tells me: This value is never used. Why? I don't understand what I did wrong? Probably something with the braces? When I try to run, it gives a compile error, saying there is no return statement.

Help is always appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The brakets are not corrected placed, it seems that you missed one in the function indexOfLargestElement. Btw, I guess that is not academically correct to return something inside the loop, but again I guess that is related with the bracket problem

Comment: actually here you just want to `return i`, and you declare `int index = 0;`. Why do you need `index` if you just want to `return i`.

Comment: hey thanks for answering! I'm not sure i really understand what you mean though :) 
Where did I forget a bracket exactly? Sorry for my noobness, the whole block thing is kind of obscure for me still.

Comment: I previously tried it, with just returning i without the index variable. I still got the value never used error at max=array[i];, so i checked my textbook, and in that example they also make a variable for index so thought i might try that, but to no avail it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on your `indexOfLargestElement()`. Here is its simplified version:

```
for(.....) {
   if(condition) {
      return something;
   } 
}
```

This means that only if in one of the loop iterations condition will be `true` the method will return value. But what if not? You have to make sure that method declared to return value does it in all scenarios.

In your case you have to decide what should you do if condition is always false. 
You can either return some kind of default value or throw exception. Do it at the end of your method:

```
int indexOfLargestElement() {
    for(.....) {
       if(condition) {
          return something;
       } 
    }
    // RETURN
    return SOME_DEFAULT;
    // OR, alternatively throw exception:
    // throw new IllegalArgumentException("Some text");

}
```

Comment: If I try this, i still get the same error for max = array[i] variable is never used.

Comment: Thank I got it! I did need index variable, and then i could place return index outside of loop!

Answer (score 0):

You put "return index" inside if statement, which makes it unsure that the return will happen 100% (that's the warning you get), just move "return index" after the loop and if statement.

Comment: if i try this, it says cannot find symbol at return i;

Comment: Thanks I got! Indeed with the index variable , and return index after the loop! return i after loop didnt work. 
Thanks for help!

Comment: In your case "i" exists only inside for loop, that's why it couldn't find it after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int indexOfLargestElement(double[] array){
    double max = array[0];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] > max) {
        max = array[i];
        index = i;
      }
    }
    return index;
```

Since you don't want to return before checking all elements, if it enters the if then max is never used.

Comment: Thanks! I got it :)
Was fiddling around with removing index variable due to other answers, but when i keep index variable and place return outside loop it works :) Thanks again!!

Comment: Please upvote/ mark answer if it was helpful enough :)

Answer (score 0):

the line "return index" should be outside the for loop.

```
public class IndexLargestElement {
public static void main(String[] args) {

 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Enter 10 double values");

 double[] list = new double [10];
 for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
   list[i] = input.nextDouble();

 int index = indexOfLargestElement(list);

 System.out.println("The index of the largest element is " + index);
}    

 public static int indexOfLargestElement(double[] array){
double max = array[0];
int index = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i] > max) {
    max = array[i];
    index = i;

  }
}
return index;
}
```

Comment: thanks! got it! return statement outside loop did the trick indeed :)
Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome ! glad to help :)